# How do I get rid of smells and tastes leaching into other cookies when stored together for gifts?

Tags: cookies

how to prevent cookies picking up the smell and taste of other cookies when storing together - Like Mint or Peanu Butter that makes all the other cookies taste like them.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you're going to accomplish that is to (shrink)-wrap them individually or to put small hermetically sealed tin or plastic boxes inside a larger box...

Mint is just too powerful not to leach into everything and that's why the professionals:

- shrink-wrap them individually or per type
- sell a box per type ("Chocolate cookies", "fruit cookies" , ...)

<sub>Sorry: probably not what you wanted to hear...</sub>